# Can I write a SQL script to dynamically create all stored procedures and views from one database to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can I write a SQL script to dynamically create all stored procedures and views from one database to another?:

- I have 2 instances of `MyDatabase`

  - 1 `MyDatabase` instance on `ServerX`
  - 1 `MyDatabase` instance on `ServerY`

I'd like to write a SQL script which does the following:

1. Drop all stored procedures and views on `ServerY`
2. Generate `CREATE` statements for all stored procedures and views on `ServerX`
3. Execute those `CREATE` statements on `ServerY`, so all stored procedures and views on `ServerY` match those on `ServerX`

I'm sure this can be done but can anyone here describe a way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this - SQL Server can script the creation of the objects for you into a single *.sql file. You then just run that script on the other server. You can even have it include the data from the existing database. For a detailed walk through, see: https://dzone.com/articles/generate-database-scripts-with-data-in-sql-server

Comment: Actually, you can script triggers too. Just click _Advanced_ in the _Set Scripting Options_ step and set _Script Triggers_ to **true**.

Comment: @User9393635 You might want to consider marking you question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Why? SQL Server has all this built in for you

Once all your SP and views are on Server.. Right click on your database and click Tasks > Generate scripts. SQL Server Management Studio is able to generate the CREATE scripts for you, which can be done on SP, views and more.

Then you simple copy this script and execute it on ServerX server/database.

BUT if you need it to be automated you should use powershell to simulate this task. Doing this in a SQL script isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link from the server X to the server Y and select, assume server x for the primary.